# How to calculate Jaccard similarity coefficient with sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, statistics, coefficients

I have a database made with sqlite3 where each user has 3 possible hobbies, which are saved as a boolean value (1 if the user likes it, 0 if he doesn't). 
I want to get a list of the pairs that are similar ordered by their Jaccard similarity coefficient, which means I have to count the number of hobbies that are true for both  of them and divide it by the number of hobbies that either of them chose.

[I have created this VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtrF1.png)
All of the pairs must contain wonka in the view. Carros, tecnologia and comida are hobbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to store all hobbies in a single row per user, and joining them (Like your view appears to be doing), and then trying to add them up, it's a lot easier to calculate with a better database design that expresses the *relationships* between users and hobbies by tracking them in another table (Think about what needs to be done to add a fourth hobby.). You'll want to look up terms like *many-to-many relationship* and *junction table* for more, and/or find a good resource on database design.

With a design like that, given these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users(userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userName TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE hobbies(hobbyID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, hobbyName TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE interests(userID INTEGER REFERENCES users(userID) ON DELETE CASCADE
                     , hobbyID INTEGER REFERENCES hobbies(hobbyID) ON DELETE CASCADE
                     , liked INTEGER
                     , PRIMARY KEY(userID, hobbyID)) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

you can calculate the similarity coefficient for all pairs with something like:

```
SELECT u1.userName AS "Person 1", u2.UserName AS "Person 2"
     , ifnull(total(i1.liked AND i2.liked) / total(i1.liked OR i2.liked), 0.0) AS Similarity
FROM users AS u1
JOIN users AS u2 ON u1.userId <> u2.userId
LEFT JOIN interests AS i1 ON u1.userId = i1.userId
LEFT JOIN interests AS i2 ON u2.userId = i2.userId AND i1.hobbyId = i2.hobbyID
GROUP BY u1.userId, u2.userId;
```